# Schematic "library" not found in collection "@schematics/angular"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a library in angular cli

```
Schematic "library" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
Error: Schematic "library" not found in collection
"@schematics/angular".
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (/home/rafaelvicio/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:143:23)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (/home/rafaelvicio/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/collection.js:12:29)
    at Object.getSchematic (/home/rafaelvicio/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js:47:23)
    at Class.run (/home/rafaelvicio/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/schematic-get-options.js:12:40)
    at Class.beforeRun (/home/rafaelvicio/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:101:31)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/home/rafaelvicio/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:138:24)
    at <anonymous>
```

Command `ng --version`

shows this

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 


node -v
v8.9.3

npm -v
5.5.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library support starts from Angular cli version 6 & above...

Please Check the [release note](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases) for more information...

Comment: same with cli version 7 :-)

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when I tried to generate a service `myService`:

```sh
ng generate myService
```

This fixed the problem:

```sh
ng generate service myService
```

Why can't someone make a UNIX shell that does what I want, not what I type? :-)

Comment: Yes - I left out the type of what I wanted to generate

Answer (score 3):

```
npm i -g @schematics/angular
```

updates you to the latest version of the schematic. 
Also important to update your angular cli:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Did both, no cigar.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`npm i @schematics/angular`

Answer (score 0):

ng config cli.defaultCollection @ngrx/schematics